# Null Pointer Exception at setAdapter

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

EDIT: Turns out I just don't know enough about Tabbed Activities... But thanks for the help!

I have searched for nearly an hour now why my code trows an NPE at setAdapter. Here's the part of code that issues the NPE (Line 83 and 84, the error being at line 84)

```
ListView cList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
cList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listitems));
```

"listitems" is defined as

```
String[] listitems= {"A","b","C","d","E","f"};
```

Heres the full myActivity.java: http://pastebin.com/ymiKRUc4

That's what LogCat says: http://pastebin.com/gPZYtXng

My fragment_myactivity.xml is just

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylistview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my activity_myactivity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.myapp.myActivity" />
```

Comment: you sure `cList` is not null?

Comment: What does the layout XML for `myActivity` look like?

Comment: You should copy and paste the code and error message here.

Comment: `cList` is `null`. You need to find out why.

Comment: Please post your `activity_myactivity.xml` file.

Comment: The code you have given uses `activity_myactivity.xml`. Which class loads `fragment_myactivity.xml`? Is it a subclass of `Fragment`?

Comment: Now show your Fragment subclass which uses `fragment_myactivity.xml` (and look at my answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myActivity` inflates `activity_myactivity.xml` for its layout:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_myactivity);
```

However, `mylistview` is in `fragment_myactivity.xml`. I assume that you inflate this XML file in a `Fragment` subclass which overrides `onCreateView()`. This is the method where you need to put

```
ListView cList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
cList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listitems));
```

Note that the views inflated by a fragment are not available in `Activity.onCreate()`, so `findViewById()` will return `null` for these views.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new to Android App development, so I have no clue where I should inflate the XML... All the code was pre-generated by Eclipse/AndroidSDK and I just added the ListView part. I followed a tutorial to do so (even multiple, because it wouldn't work with the code of any of them) What would I have to do  for it to just work "normally" without any special classes processing the Adapter and List views?

Comment: @user3133603 I think you are trying to tackle too many things all at once. You have code for a `ViewPager` and a tabbed navigation system along with code for a `ListView`. This seems strange to me. What are you trying to accomplish? What is your UI design?

Comment: @user3133603 I'm not sure what you mean by "normally". What do you want your UI to look like?

Comment: The code works fine without the ListView part. And the UI should look like: Tabs at the top (they're there) and a list view as the content

Comment: @user3133603 So the list view is on one of the tabs? Then it should definitely be part of a `Fragment`, not in the `Activity`.

Comment: @user3133603 You definitely need to read more about fragments. For now, you can move the lines of code that deal with the list view down to the `onCreateView()` method in the `PlaceHolderFragment` class. Ideally, you should make your own fragment class which has a more descriptive name, maybe even more than one if you have different layouts in each tab.

Comment: Yeah... Oh well, then it really might be too much at once... Then I'll read stuff on the tabs and try again. But thank you very much though!

Comment: @user3133603 You might want to create some "learning apps" separate from your main project. One could use just a `ListView`, one can use a simple `Fragment`, and another use a `ViewPager`.